# Sequence contains no matching element while it found the element once

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using [this code](https://github.com/cornflourblue/aspnet-core-3-jwt-refresh-tokens-api) for a small project to provide the jwt auth.

The problem is in case of revoking the refresh token, the following code from `UsersController` would fail in line 5:

```
1.  private (RefreshToken, Account) getRefreshToken(string token)
2.  {
3.      var account = _context.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(u => u.RefreshTokens.Any(t => t.Token == token));
4.      if (account == null) throw new AppException("Invalid token");
5.      var refreshToken = account.RefreshTokens.Single(x => x.Token == token);
6.      if (!refreshToken.IsActive) throw new AppException("Invalid token");
7.      return (refreshToken, account);
8.  }
```

It passes line 3 and 4, so it means it could find the RefreshToken and the related account in line 3; however, later in line 5 I have encountered with the following error:

> "message": "Sequence contains no matching element"

Here is a picture of the error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly that `RefreshTokens` is a navigational property on `Account` entity:

Have you tried to `Include()` it?

```csharp
_context.Accounts.Include(x => x.RefreshTokens).SingleOrDefault(u => u.RefreshTokens.Any(t => t.Token == token));
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer. Didn't notice that I need to include it.

Comment: Yeah, it might not be entirely obvious actually, since if you filter based on a navigational property's property, the SQL statement will contain the JOIN for the navigational property, so you could think that it's included... But the SELECT still won't contain it.

Comment: Maybe using `UseLazyLoadingProxies` can be helpful in this case: https://www.koskila.net/ef-core-returns-null-for-a-navigation-property/